Touchpad mapped to absolute screen coordinates on screen
I connected an external keyboard with a touchpad via Bluetooth. Every time I press the left edge of the touchpad, it causes a click on the left edge of the screen. It also seems that the touchpad is always pressed, as in, if I move the cursor around, it always tries to select everything on the way as if the left mouse button were pressed.
I am on ubuntu 22.04 and here's some details about the touchpad-
Device 'SMARTDEVIL':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 0.500000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000, 0.879479, 0.120521, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (324):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (325):   0
    libinput Calibration Matrix (364):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (365):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (309): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (310):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (311):    0, 0
    Device Node (312):  "/dev/input/event15"
    Device Product ID (313):    1452, 591
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (340):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (341):   1
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (344):    1

Here's udevadm info:
P: /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:05AC:024F.0007/input/input28/event15
N: input/event15
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:05AC:024F.0007/input/input28/event15
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event15
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=79
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=12240226655
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=101
E: ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=68
E: ID_BUS=bluetooth
E: XKBMODEL=pc105
E: XKBLAYOUT=us
E: BACKSPACE=guess
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=5/5ac/24f:b0:68:e6:0b:a0:6e
E: TAGS=:power-switch:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:power-switch:


I tried looking at debug events:
sudo libinput debug-events --device=/dev/input/event15 
-event15  DEVICE_ADDED            SMARTDEVIL                        seat0 default group1  cap:kp  size 101x69mm scroll-nat calib
 event15  POINTER_MOTION_ABSOLUTE +0.015s   38.59/ 99.89
 event15  POINTER_MOTION_ABSOLUTE +0.030s   38.84/ 99.89


Could you also provide udevadm info /dev/input/event16?

@grawity Thanks, I have added that info. It's now at  /dev/input/event15. The device is being treated as a touchscreen. How do I fix this?

I have been able to change it to ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=0. It's still mapped to absolute screen coordinates, but at least the selection behaviour is gone.
